# build android with clang instead of gcc ? and the clang stl lib instead of gnustl lib?

Tags: android, gcc, c++11, android-ndk, clang

Am trying to build an android ndk app using clang instead of gcc, for know i have tried this
in the Android.mk

```
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := clang
LOCAL_CLANG :=true
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -lc++_static
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -std=c++11
```

and in the Application.mk

```
APP_PLATFORM    := android-9
APP_STL         := libc++_static
APP_CPPFLAGS    := -fexceptions -frtti
APP_ABI         := armeabi-v7a
```

but it always give me link errors with the std library.

Any help is appreciated  !

Comment: Post the link errors you get...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are several mistakes in your *.mk files:

`libc++_static` isn't a proper value for APP_STL, it should be `c++_static` here.

`NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION` has no effect when set inside Android.mk, it should be set inside *Application.mk*

`LOCAL_CLANG` is a variable used inside system modules from AOSP, not when using the NDK.

Since you're setting APP_STL as `c++_static`, the NDK toolchain will correctly tell the linker what lib to use, you shouldn't add `LOCAL_LDLIBS := -lc++_static`.

Also, you set `APP_ABI` to only armeabi-v7a, is it on purpose ? Android runs on other architectures as well and you'll get better performance on these if you also compile your libraries accordingly. You can either set `APP_ABI` to `all` or to a list of architectures `armeabi-v7a x86`...

In summary:

*Android.mk*

```
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -std=c++11
```

*Application.mk*

```
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := clang

APP_PLATFORM    := android-9
APP_STL         := c++_static
APP_CPPFLAGS    := -fexceptions -frtti
APP_ABI         := all
```

If you continue having some troubles compiling your code, please show the exact errors you're getting.

Comment: I am trying to build pugixml. I am getting following error always [arm64-v8a] Compile++      : spugixmllib <= pugixml.cpp
clang: for the -aarch64-fix-cortex-a53-835769 option: may only occur zero or one times!
make: *** [obj/local/arm64-v8a/objs/spugixmllib/pugixml/src/pugixml.o] Error 1 . We cant build pugixml for arm64? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -2):

The building settings are correct,
mostly this is happens because you are linking with library that use gcc instead of clang. check if all your linked library using clang !